# How to define compensation in redux-saga?

Tags: redux, redux-saga, reactjs

Saga pattern defines that each transaction has a corresponding compensation. However, I cannot find any information about compensation in the official documents.

How to define compensation in redux-saga?

Compensation means that redux-saga uses try-catch to define compensation after `take()` an action ?